# gulp minify assets when laravel environment is in production

Tags: laravel, gulp

I am using Laravel framework. Is there any method that can trigger gulp to minify the assets when the application is running in the production environment?

Here is the gulp task that I want to run.

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var concat = require('gulp-concat');
var minifyCSS = require('gulp-minify-css');
var autoprefixer = require('gulp-autoprefixer');

// css minification task
gulp.task('css', function(){
    gulp.src('app/assets/css/**/*.css')
        .pipe(minifyCSS())
        .pipe(autoprefixer('last 2 version', 'safari 5', 'ie 8', 'ie 9', 'opera 12.1', 'ios 6', 'android 4'))
        .pipe(concat('style.min.css'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('public/assets/css'))
});
```

Answer (score 1):

In case you're using Laravel Forge, add `gulp --production` to the 'deploy script' to automatically minify the assets upon deployment of the application.

Answer (score 0):

I highly suggest Laravel Elixir.

Link: https://github.com/laravel/elixir

It allows you to do everything that gulp does through the Laravel framework rather than having to deal with gulp and set it up how you would normally.

It's brand new and I believe only works with L5.

Comment: @astro - you can use something like [Motdotla/Dotenv](https://github.com/motdotla/dotenv)

Comment: @james actually i solved that my problem the same week using Motdotla/dotenv package :)